# Running "composer update" leads to errors with coder

Tags: 8, updating, composer

```
...
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
  - Updating drupal/coder (8.2.12 => 8.3.1)    The package has modified files:
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/ArrayUnitTest.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/ArrayUnitTest.inc.fixed
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/ArrayUnitTest.php
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.php
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/disallow_long_array_d7/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.1.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/disallow_long_array_d7/disallow_long_array_d7.info
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/disallow_long_array_d8/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.2.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/disallow_long_array_d8/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.2.inc.fixed
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Array/disallow_long_array_d8/disallow_long_array_d8.info.yml
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Classes/ClassCreateInstanceUnitTest.inc


  [ErrorException]                 
  A non-numeric value encountered
```

I have tried with errors

```
$ composer require drupal/coder ^8.3  
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/debug (locked at v4.1.7, required as ^3.4.0) is satisfiable by symfony/debug[v4.1.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/annotations v1.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/annotations v1.6.0
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.0, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.1, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.2, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.3, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.4, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.5, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.6, v1.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/annotations[v1.2.7, v1.6.0].
    - Installation request for doctrine/annotations (locked at v1.6.0, required as ^1.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.6.0].
    - Installation request for doctrine/annotations 1.2.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.2.3, v1.2.4, v1.2.5, v1.2.6, v1.2.7].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Also tried with errors

```
rm vendor/ -rf 
composer update
....
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package doctrine/annotations 1.2.* exists as doctrine/annotations[v1.6.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

but always end up with other errors 
Any thoughts ?

Comment: `composer require drupal/coder ^8.3` mising the colon on the version number? Also shouldn't it be `^3.0` for the module version?

Comment: @Kevin you are right I have also tried `composer require drupal/coder:^3.0` with similar results.  The wrong  `composer require drupal/coder ^8.3` was probably out of desperation.  I don't remember where I picked it up.   Thanks for the comment, I think I have found a way and I will post soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked is the following commands

```
rm composer.lock
rm vendor -rf
composer clear-cache
composer require --dev drupal/coder
composer update
```

with last command perhaps not needed as the previous composer command does an implicit `update`

Answer (score 1):

You should not really rm anything it is not required.

> composer remove drupal/coder
>   composer require --dev drupal/coder

Also for a bonus point it's often a good idea to include the hash in the composer file incase an unstable dev is released you won't have to worry about changes that have come after.